# why is my Tab blank when i add it into microsoft teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

i followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview) to add a tab. but when i added it into my team, a blank page is displayed.

My webpage can be iframed. how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked **validDomains** in your menifest.json? the domain of your webpage should be added into validDomains.

if it is ok, you can use [teams web](https://teams.microsoft.com) to debug it(Chrome F12 developer tool)

Comment: is it possible to debug it on desktop application?

Comment: you can enable "developer preview" to debug it. follow the official documentation.

Comment: @rafe Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-tools) to debug the app on your desktop application.